# How to bind label to first letter of StringProperty?

Tags: java, string, javafx, bind

I have `StringProperty` that consists of two letters (example: 06) that are constantly changing. I have two labels, which I want to bind to each letter of StringProperty, like `label1="0"` and `label2="6"`. Is there a way to bind label to specific letter of `StringProperty`?

My code:

```
@FXML
private Label hoursLabel1;

@FXML
private Label hoursLabel2;

private StringProperty hours;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    hoursLabel1.textProperty().bind(hours);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Bindings.createStringBinding(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createStringBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-):

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    hoursLabel1.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> 
        hours.get().substring(0,1), hours));
    hoursLabel2.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> 
        hours.get().substring(1,2), hours));
}
```